# Drawing multiple objects in 2D with OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to render multiple sprites in OpenGL and would like some advice concerning efficiency. I'm probably missing a key concept too.

In my example, I'm using an `orthographic` projection to transpose the viewport coordinates to normalized device coordintates.

Each *sprite* will also have a `model` matrix.

The vertex shader contains the following code:

```
#version 410

layout (location=0) in vec2 a_position;

uniform mat4 u_model;
uniform mat4 u_projection;

void main() {
  vec4 pos = vec4(a_position.x, a_position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl_Position = u_projection * u_model * pos;
}
```

And the fragment shader is very simple:

```
#version 410

out vec4 frag_color;

void main() {
  frag_color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

After creating a window with `GLFW` and initializing the GL context,
I retreive the `attributes` from my shader:

```
GLuint u_model = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "u_model");
GLuint u_projection = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "u_projection");
```

I create a `VAO` and a `VBO` that will contain the triangle vertices

(*and that's where I think I'm getting it wrong*)

```
GLfloat vertices[6] = {
     0.0, -1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,
     1.0,  1.0
};

GLuint vao;
GLuint vbo;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), 
    vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, 
    GL_FALSE, 
    2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*) 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I also setup the orthographic projection:

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f,
        (float) viewport_width, (float) viewport_height,
        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

glUniformMatrix4fv(u_projection, 1, 
    GL_FALSE, (const float*) glm::value_ptr(projection));
```

I then instantiate a few *sprites*

```
const int MAX_SPRITES = 10;
struct sprite {
  float rotation;
  glm::vec2 position;
  glm::vec2 size;
};
sprite sprites[MAX_SPRITES];

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SPRITES; i++) {
    float x = 20.0f + (i * 50.0f);
    float y = (float) viewport_height * 0.5;

    sprites[i].position = glm::vec2(x, y);
    sprites[i].rotation = 0.0f;
    sprites[i].size = 20.0f;
}
```

Then in the *render loop*, I update the sprites `rotation` and draw them

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SPRITES; i++) {
    sprites[i].rotation += elapsed_seconds;

    glm::mat4 model = draw_sprite( 
        sprites[i].position, sprites[i].size, 
        sprites[i].rotation);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(u_model, 
        1, GL_FALSE, 
        (const float*) glm::value_ptr(model));

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

The function `draw_sprite` is defined like this:

```
glm::mat4 draw_sprite
(glm::vec2 position, glm::vec2 size, GLfloat rotate) {
    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(position, 1.0f));

    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(
        0.5 * size.x, 0.5f * size.y, 0.0));
    model = glm::rotate(model, rotate, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(
        -0.5 * size.x, -0.5f * size.y, 0.0));

    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(size, 1.0f));
    return model;
}
```

While this works, calling `glUniformMatrix4fv` and `glDrawArrays` in this loop doesn't seem like the best idea.

Wouldn't it be better to send the "transformed" sprite coordinates in the `VBO` and remove the model matrix from the shader? 
If so how could that be done? 
Or should I concatenate all the model matrices into one matrix and use that?

Is there is a more efficient or standard way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should look into [instancing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing). You'll only know if it is faster the the simple glUniform*/glDraw* loop if you try it out.

Comment: @BDL: I wouldn't recommend instancing. Instancing will be efficient if the base mesh has many vertices, with just a quad you will not make good use of the GPU ressources. I'd recommend putting a const array of the base vertices in the shader, and the per-quad data in an UBO or SSBO, and simply use `gl_VertexID % 6` for the vertex index (assuming 6 vertices for two triangles) and `gl_VertexID / 6` as index into the per-sprite array, and just drawing attribute-less with `6*number_of_sprites` vertices.

Comment: Thanks to both
At the end I used something similar to what is decribed here: http://voidptr.io/blog/2016/04/28/ldEngine-Part-1.html